# Linear Layout won't take the height of its parent in percentRelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Android, and I have a list view with row views that have the following content in them:

[image]

All of these views are wrapped in a `PercentRelativeLayout`, because I want to keep the widths proportional. So the issue I'm running into is that since the two layouts on the left are left empty and filled at runtime (there is absolutely no way around this) their height is measured out to 0, which then sets the `Rowview` height to 0, and that then sets the controls layout off to the right to have a height of 0, which then stretches to the size of the largest control inside of it (ex:)

[image]

I have tried:

- Using layout weights and a height of 0 to allow the layout itself to stretch to fill the parent
- Using layout weights on the controls themselves within the layout
- Scrapping a layout altogether, and simply wrapping the image buttons in the PercentRelativeLayout, and using layout positions to position them properly
- Using percentage based layout widths and heights within the children to fill the height (this only seems to work for the width, but not height)
- Adding dummy views as padding to push the controls layout into position
- Adding percentage based margins to the layout itself, the children, the padding dummy views, and every combination of those

Not one single thing I have tried has had any effect, the only thing that affects the height of the linear layout is simply hard-coding the height.

My question then is how can I tell this layout to occupy the full height of the rowview once everything has been measured? (Please let me know if you have any other questions to help address this, I'm happy to oblige)

EDIT #1: Here is my xml for the rowview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="400dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/LeadRowHolder">

  <!--Tag Holder-->
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/LeadTagLayout">

  </RelativeLayout>

  <!--Details Holder-->
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/LeadDetailsLayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/LeadTagLayout"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">
    <android.webkit.WebView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/leadShortDescription"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <!--Controls Holder-->
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_widthPercent="20%"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/LeadControlsLayout"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/LeadTagLayout"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <ImageButton
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:id="@+id/MenuCall3x"
      android:background="@drawable/MenuCall3x"/>
    <ImageButton
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:id="@+id/MenuFwd3x"
      android:background="@drawable/MenuFwd3x"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think your percentlayout should have `wrap_content` as `layout_height`. Why match_parent?

Comment: @MatPag It doesn't affect it either way, however the reason I went with match parent was because I assumed that would give the rowview a set height it could use at runtime, but the height gets computed to zero until the adapter fills out the listview no matter what I do (and since it doesn't affect the layout either way, I _believe_ that match_parent is more efficient because it reduces the number of measures it takes for Android to compute the dimensions of the view, since it just takes on whatever the parents computed height is, unless some sort of optimization happens I don't know about.)

Comment: To clarify, I did go ahead and try what you said, I meant to say it doesn't fix the issue even after trying it.

Comment: I don't like your approach sincerely. i've never seen a webview in each row of a list...

You should set a fixed height to the webview if it is really necessary, and you should use different type of rows layout instead of adding views manually at runtime in the relative layout. The inflation process of your complex rows will be really slow and user experience could be impacted on some devices

Comment: @MatPag A WebView would be slow to have in each row except we're just loading a raw html string, so it's really just reading in html, formatting it and displaying it, so it's marginally faster than actually loading a webpage. To be clear I agree with you that it will be slower, this is how the company has decided they want to do it to simplify formatting text across Android and iOS.

Comment: @MatPag So let me ask this then, for the time being, is there a way that I can do what I'm wanting to do? All I want to do is set a linear layout to have the height of the percentrelativelayout once the other two layouts have been measured. I agree with all your points, but there's not really anything I can do about it for the time being.

Comment: You want to achieve the result of the first image of your question?

Comment: @MatPag Correct, and the result I'm getting is the second image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played a bit with your code, and the result seems good.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/LeadRowHolder">

    <!--Tag Holder-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/LeadTagLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="this is a test"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Details Holder-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/LeadDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/LeadTagLayout">
        <android.webkit.WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/leadShortDescription"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!--Controls Holder-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_widthPercent="20%"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/LeadControlsLayout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/LeadTagLayout"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/MenuCall3x"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/MenuFwd3x"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if this works for you at runtime (i've removed some background drawable files which you didn't provided to test this XML).
I've added a TextView inside the RelativeLayout to test his height

Comment: Unreal, all I needed was centerVertical="True"....Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: I did go ahead and add minHeight for the webviews too, what benefit does that add? just out of curiosity.

Comment: It should help calculating the height of the view. But this depends on what your are loading inside of it. You can remove it and it should work without problems.

Comment: Don't forget that Percent library has been deprecated starting from support libraries 26.X.X. It has been replaced by `ConstraintLayout` library

Comment: I noticed that the other night, I will be keeping that in mind going forward.